# Random particle rotation

Tags: particles

I am trying to make gravel underneath this track using a particle system and a weight map.

However the rocks all have the same rotation and are arranged in a grid-like pattern and I can't see any option to randomize these.

[image]
[image]

[image]

These are my particle settings.

[image]
[image]

I haven't been able to find any tutorials on this so some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can always [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/192204/edit) to add new information. Not everyone will look at the comments :)

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109818/86891 tldr : Enable "Advanced" at the top of the settings and a new "Rotation" panel will appear. Also the settings to randomize placement are under "Emission / Source"

Answer (score 3):

You could try a couple things to improve your results. One is to use [*Brownian Force*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/physics/newtonian.html#forces) under the physics properties of the particle settings.
From the manual:

> Brownian
>
> Specify the amount of Brownian motion. Brownian motion adds random motion to the particles based on a Brownian noise field. This is nice
> to simulate small, random wind forces.

Also, you may use the [rotation values](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/rotation.html#rotation), which does provide a random parameter underneath the advanced tab.

Here are the settings that I used:

[image]
[image]

Furthermore, using multiple objects will help in your instance collection. The repetition will not be nearly as noticeable if you use 5 or more objects as if you only use one.

Here is the result:

[image]

As for the grid pattern, you can vary the density of your density group when you are in weight paint mode if needed. This is an image of my example:

[image]